# How to get the corresponding values of a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have 2 lists A & B. I want to check the list A for input "Nein" and if that is true, then I want to get the corresponding text from the list B and use the output (eg:A) as an input in the next command. And this has to iterate over the entire list (else, pass the loop).

I used pandas to extract these 2 columns from an excel and made it into lists.

```
A = [Nein, Ja, Nein, Ja, Nein, Nein]
B = [A, B, C, D, E, F]

for i in A:
    if i == "Nein":
    print(i)
    ????
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists and iterate over them together

```py
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    if a == "Nein":
        print(b)
```

However if you have a pandas dataframe `df` with the columns then you can filter to use the rows that have `A == "Nein"` by doing `df[df.A == "Nein"]`

Comment: Is it possible to change the values inside a list after the iteration. Eg: After the first iteration, can i change the first input from "Nein" to "Ja" ?? After the first iteration : ´A = [Ja, Ja, Nein, Ja, Nein, Nein]`

Answer (score 1):

We could combine the two lists into a dictionary, and extract the value of a particular key, given the conditions are satisfied.

The code below demonstrates the process of zipping two lists and converting into a dictionary.

```
dict(zip(a,b))
```

Implementing the above to your code:

```
for i,x in dict(zip(a,b)).items():
    if i == 'Nein':
        print(x)
```

Or if you do not want to create a dict, then you could consider GiuppeP's approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your structure:

```
A = ["Nein", "Ja", "Nein", "Ja", "Nein", "Nein"]
B = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] == "Nein":
        print(B[i])
```

Then your will have two printed values, the index where a "Nein" was found, and his correct capital letter. The output:

```
A
C
E
F
```

I am assuming that the order of list A and list B are the same, so there is a correspondence.